# how can i add my music player for my website

Tags: html

i need with start button

I wrote it correctly but it doesn't work on the site.
`<audio autoplay>  <source src="file way" type="audio/mpeg">  </audio>`

Comment: looks like you are missing the src - you should replace the "file way" with the Link to your file

Comment: i still do this but not working on website

Comment: are both your html page and audio in the same folder? if not, are you using the right relative url for this? it is hard to tell what is the problem like that, without more context

Comment: </header>
            <audio autoplay> 
                 <source src="sound/sound.mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">  </audio>
            <div class="consolebody">
yes

Comment: you have a different type in the html and in the link (audio/mpeg - mp3).and why do you have .mp3 twice?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a clear or valid explanation of behavior. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with an explanation of the current behavior, your desired behavior, and any error messages that you may be encountering. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on how to improve your question. Also see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/10601203).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a very similar problem playing video. The folder path I provided as the "src" to the video file actually existed, but was outside the document root of the web application. Thus it was invisible and inaccessible.

When I changed the "src" to a folder *within* the document root, the webapp worked as expected.

Be sure src="path" points to a folder that exists somewhere within the document root of your webapp.

```
DocRoot is /Users/horace/Sites/VideoMash
Video files are in /Users/horace/Sites/VideoMash/videos

❌ <video src="/Users/horace/Sites/VideoMash/videos/xyz.mp4" ...>

✅ <video src="videos/xyz.mp4" ...>
```

Hopefully this addresses your problem.